# What is the most recent vtk file format description?

Tags: version, vtk, file-format

The Visualisation Toolkit (VTK) release is currently version 9.0.0., see [here](https://vtk.org/download/). VTK website provides this [file format description](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjjsouqla7qAhUOsKQKHS5oA2oQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vtk.org%2FVTK%2Fimg%2Ffile-formats.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3SgbI6PQRAy15-tBTG2VXE), which is titled "VTK Version 4.2". [Paraview](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats) also links this [github page](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKFileFormats/), which seems to be the same as the Version 4.2 description, and to the 4.2-description.

What is the most recent VTK-File Format description? Or is the linked 4.2-description the one that is used in the most recent release version (currently 9.0.0)?

Comment: This is the most recent version of the format and what is being used in VTK 9.0.0.

Comment: I think we met in Shanghai at the OpenFOAM conference :) Is there any location where I could have found this information online?

Comment: I'm afraid not. We should improve this doc and make this information clear.

Comment: I would accept this as the answer. If you touch the documentation you may change `4 5 11 10 14` to `4 8 11 10 14` for the unstructured mesh example on p.10 and give this tetrahedral cell some volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most recent version of the format and what is being used in VTK 9.0.0.

This information is not documented anywhere yet.